# Disable and Enable ToolStripMenuItem Programmatically

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I'm setting up a User and Admin Permissions which works perfectly well but I want to disable some ToolStripMenuItem from "Users" but Enable them only for "Admin".

Here's the code that logs User and Admin in depending on their Roles.

```
if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
{
  if (ComboBox_LoginAs.SelectedIndex == 0)
{
  this.Hide();                     
  Main_Form mainSystem = new Main_Form();
  mainSystem.Show();
}
else if (ComboBox_LoginAs.SelectedIndex == 1)
{
  this.Hide();
  Main_Form mainSystem = new Main_Form();
  mainSystem.Show();

  /* disable View All Employees for Users */

  ViewAllEmployeesToolStripMenuItem.Enable = false;
}
```

I expect the Users to not be able to view all Employee Records except the Admin.
I hope this question will not get down voted.

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: There are a couple of different ways to handle this. The easiest is going to create a new class called Admin or whatever you want. Inherit from User and set a "Security rating" variable for the admin. This would allow you to check if User IS A Admin then do such and such... you'd need to implement an interface to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of an interface I used once that accomplishes something similar.

## Main

```
namespace UnNamed Project
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            User user;
            user = new SuperUser("Bob", "12345");

            if (user.Login())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Welcome {user.Name}");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error has occured.");
            }

            Utility.PauseBeforeContinuing();
        }
    }
}
```

## Interface Class

```
namespace UnNamed Project
{
    interface ILoginHandler
    {
        bool HandleLogin();
        void SetPassword(string password);
    }
}
```

## User Class

```
namespace UnNamed Project
{
    abstract class User
    {
        private string _name;
        private int _securityLevel;

        public User(string name, int securityLevel)
        {
            _name = name;
            _securityLevel = securityLevel;
        }

        abstract public bool Login();
    }
}
```

## SuperUser Class

```
namespace UnNamed Project
{
    class SuperUser : User
    {
        private ILoginHandler _loginHandler;

        public SuperUser(string name, string password) : base(name, 10)
        {
            _loginHandler = new FaceLogin(password);
        }

        public override bool Login()
        {
            return _loginHandler.HandleLogin();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, if setup properly you can create an object "User" and another object "Admin" and then create an abstract method within user. You can alternatively do a virtual method to handle the login, just make sure that your admin class has an override for it's own Login() method. This will cause the program to use the method directly related to the object.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I tried changing my MenuStripItem Modifier state to "public". Then I created an object on my main form.

```
public static Main_Form GetMainForm_Obj;
public Main_Form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Then inside my Form Load, I added:

```
private void Main_Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        eMPLOYEESToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;

        GetMainForm_Obj = this;
    }
```

And finally, in my Login form:

```
 if (ComboBox_LoginAs.SelectedIndex == 0)
  {
     this.Hide();
     Main_Form mainSystem = new Main_Form();
     mainSystem.Show();
  }
  else if (ComboBox_LoginAs.SelectedIndex == 1)
  {
     this.Hide();
     Main_Form mainSystem = new Main_Form();
     mainSystem.Show();

     Main_Form.GetMainForm_Obj.eMPLOYEESToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
   }
```

Thank you everyone!